# invoking a servlet in java

Tags: java, servlets, post, get

How do i invoke a Servlet? and What is the difference in between doPost and doGet? any links for explanation are welcome

thank you

Comment: It sounds like you have not read any documentation on the Servlet API. Start with the [Servlet section of the Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

Comment: Yep the JavaDoc is pretty useful stuff too - http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html

Comment: @Laurent, that link is old and out-of-date. It hasn't been called "J2EE" for many years.

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[servlets]` tag below the question and wait until a popbox pops up. In the popbox, click ["info"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) link. That's a good starting point.

Comment: @Matt Ball: True, but the answers to the question are there and haven't changed since.

Answer (score 5):

A servlet is typically invoked via a *servlet mapping* in your servlet container configuration, when a request is made to the servlet container for a path matching that mapping. There are a number of resources for learning more about servlets on the <s>Sun</s> [Oracle Java site's servlet page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html). There's also an introductory article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlet). **Edit**: In the comments, @BalusC points out that StackOverflow's own [page for the `servlet` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) has quite a lot of useful info and links — nice one, Balus.

[`doPost`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) is called when the HTTP request is a `POST`. [`doGet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) is called when it's a `GET`. There are other methods corresponding to the other HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 3):

Invoking a servlet is done simply by navigating to the URL specified in your web.xml file in your web application.  So if your servlet is called MyServlet you may have some code like this in your web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.mycompany.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this setup, navigating to http://myapplication.com/myservlet would invoke your servlet.

As far as the difference in doGet and doPost, the only difference is the HTTP method they respond to, as the servlet API abstracts any differences between actual HTTP GET and HTTP POST methods away from the programmer.  This abstraction allows the programmer to get parameters from the request using a single interface and not have to bother with how the parameters were passed in.  doGet is called when a HTTP GET request is sent to your servlet, typically by navigating to it directly.  doPost is called when an HTTP POST request is sent to your servlet, which is commonly done with a form post from another html page.

Comment: @Brad - I though GET and POST do differ in some respects. Can you pass parameters using GET other than adding them as URL parameters? I didn't think GET allowed you to pass parameters in the body of the message in the way that POST does.

Comment: @Dave: I don't quite understand why that would possibly form a problem. If you need to pass info by body, just use POST.

Comment: @DaveHowes: That's correct; however, the `HttpServletRequest` class makes access to name/value pair data (from the query string or from a standard form POST) accessible via a single interface, so programmatically you don't always have to spend much effort worrying about where the field came from. (You can when you need to, though.) Naturally, if you're responding to a POST with a different type of payload (which isn't uncommon), then you have to handle that explicitly (and in `doPost`).

Comment: The HTTP methods definitely differ, and in the ways that you mention, but the difference between doGet and doPost in a servlet is simply which one is called and when.

Comment: @BalusC - I agree with what you say, I was referring to Brad's initial statement that "the only difference is the HTTP method they respond to".

Comment: I edited my answer to clear up the differences using a bit of DaveHowes comment.

Answer (score 2):

About POST and GET: learn [some HTTP basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

And some [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servlets) basics